# How to solve $\int\ x^{\ln x} dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, closed-form

How to solve this integral

> $$\int\ x^{\ln x} dx$$

step by step?

Comment: There is no closed form expression in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: For future reference, in order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We assume $x^{\ln x}$ is well defined.

Then we make the change of variable $x=e^{u}$, $dx=e^{u}\:du$, obtaining
$$
\begin{align}
\int x^{\ln x}\:dx&=\int e^{(\ln x)^2}dx
\\&=\int e^{u^2+u}du
\\&=e^{-1/4}\int e^{(u+1/2)^2}du
\\&=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}2e^{-1/4}\: \text{erfi}\left(u+\tfrac12\right)
\end{align}
$$ where we have used the special function [$\text{erfi}(\cdot)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function).

Finally,

> $$
> \int x^{\ln x}\:dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}2e^{-1/4}\: \text{erfi}\left(\ln x+1/2\right)+C.
> $$

One may notice that
$$
\operatorname{erfi}(z)= \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^{2n+1}}{n! (2n+1)},\quad z \in \mathbb{C}.
$$

Comment: The "imaginary error function" must be an example of particularly misleading names.

Answer (score -3):

get $$u=Lnx$$
so $$du=\frac{1}{x}dx$$
the main integral became
$$\int x^{u}xdu=\int x^{u+1}du\overset{x=e^{u}}{\rightarrow}\int (e^{u})^{u+1}du=\int e^{u^2+u}=\int e^{(u+\frac{1}{2})^{2}-\frac{1}{4}}du\overset{p=u+\frac{1}{2}}{\rightarrow}e^{\frac{-1}{4}}\int e^{p^2}dp$$
We can calculate the last integral by double integration.
$$I=\int e^{p^2}dp=\int e^{q^2}dq$$
so $$I^2=\int \int e^{p^2+q^2}dpdq\overset{r^{2}=p^2+q^2}{\rightarrow}\int \int re^{r^2}drd\theta =2\pi\frac{1}{2}e^{r^2}$$
finally $$I=\sqrt{\pi}e^{r}$$
and your answer is $$ans=\sqrt{\pi}e^{r-\frac{1}{4}}$$

Comment: You are mixing up things when doing the tour on the double integral. That is possible to do for definite integrals, but in this case it does not make sense.